# How to add programmatically dependencies to Gradle configuration?

Tags: gradle

I have the following code:

```
static def getFamilyDependencies(ConfigurationContainer configurations) {
    def result = configurations.collect { configuration ->
        configuration.allDependencies.findAll { dependency ->
            dependency instanceof DefaultProjectDependency
        } collect { projectDependency ->
            projectDependency.dependencyProject.name
        }
    } flatten()

    result as Set
}
```

and I would like to test it. So far, I have:

```
@Test
void shouldGetFamilyDependencies() {
    final Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()

    final configurations = project.getConfigurations()

    configurations.create('configuration0')
    configurations.create('configuration1')

    configurations.each { configuration ->
        println "***************** ${configuration}"

        configuration.allDependencies.each {
            println "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ${it}"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add dependencies to the configurations? The following doesn't work:

```
    final Project subproject = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    configurations.configuration0 {
        subproject
    }
    configurations.configuration1 {
        allDependencies {
            subproject
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Test
void shouldGetFamilyDependenciesAcrossAllConfigurations() {
    final expected = ['subproject-0', 'subproject-1']

    final Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    final configurations = project.getConfigurations()

    configurations.create('configuration-0')
    final Project subproject0 = ProjectBuilder.builder().withName(expected[0]).build()
    project.dependencies {
        delegate.'configuration-0'(subproject0)
    }

    configurations.create('configuration-1')
    final Project subproject1 = ProjectBuilder.builder().withName(expected[1]).build()
    project.dependencies {
        delegate.'configuration-1'(subproject1)
    }

    final actual = RestorePublishedArtifactTask.getFamilyDependencies(configurations)

    assertThat(actual, hasItems(expected.toArray(new String[expected.size()])))
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick:

```
configuration.getDependencies().add(dependenyMock);
```

Comment: How do I turn subproject0 into a dependency that can be passed into `add()`?

Comment: @NovemberYankee you can do it in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992052/how-to-add-programmatically-dependencies-to-gradle-configuration/55160963#answer-55160963)

Comment: If only there was a `remove()` method :(

Answer (score 5):

Try to do it in this way:

`project.getDependencies().add('compile', project(':common-configuration'))`

`compile` - a name of the configuration
`:common-configuration` - a name of the project to add (or any other dependencies)